# Coderbyte incorrect test cases

Tags: javascript, for-loop, split

I'm working on some JS Coderbyte challenges and even though I get all the test cases correct, it says I get them all wrong. This challenge in particular is about finding the longest word. Has anyone had any issues with this? Any help is appreciated.

```
function LongestWord(sen) { 
var remove =  sen.replace(/[^a-zA-Z 0-9]+/g,"");
var keep = remove.split(" ");
var hold = 0;
var word = 0;
for(var i = 0; i < keep.length; i++) {
 if(keep[i].length > hold) {
   hold = keep[i].length;
   word = keep[i];
  }
} 
 return word;
}
LongestWord( "a b c dee");




 Ex test cases:

 "I love dogs" should output "love"
 "a confusing /:sentence:/[ this is not!!!!!!!~" should output "confusing"
 "a beautiful sentence^&!" should output "beautiful"
 "a b c dee" should output "dee"
```

Comment: I copied your code and it worked for me

Comment: Yes on coderbyte, 10/10

Comment: @Dana What the heck? So weird. I tried it at least 3 times. I'm new to Coderyte. Is there anything I should be doing besides pasting in code? Where it says "argument goes here," does that have to be filled in?

Comment: do you have this line `LongestWord( "a b c dee");`  at the end as you have above? because that would break it

Comment: @Dana ok, got it! Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Dana sorry, how is that you got 10/10? I only got 1/10?